# Regex PHP. Reduce steps: limited by fixed width Lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a regex that will be used to match @users tags.

I use lokarround assertions, letting punctuation and white space characters surround the tags.
There is an added complication, there are a type of bbcodes that represent html.
I have two types of bbcodes, inline (`^B` bold `^b`) and blocks (`^C` center `^c`).
The inline ones have to be passed thru to reach for the previous or next character.
And the blocks are allowed to surround a tag, just like punctuation.

I made a regex that does work. What I want to do now is to lower the number of steps that it does in every character that’s not going to be a match.
At first I thought I could do a regex that would just look for `@`, and when found, it would start looking at the lookarrounds, that worked without the inline bbcodes, but since lookbehind cannot be quantifiable, it’s more difficult since I cannot add `((\^[BIUbiu])++)*` inside, producing much more steps.

How could I do my regex more efficient with fewer steps?

Here is a simplified version of it, in the Regex101 link there is the full regex.

```
(?<=[,\.:=\^ ]|\^[CJLcjl])((\^[BIUbiu])++)*@([A-Za-z0-9\-_]{2,25})((\^[BIUbiu])++)*(?=[,\.:=\^ ]|\^[CJLcjl])
```

https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/4/

Comment: This looks like a very complicated case, which also makes any resultant regex error-prone... I think it should probably broken into smaller steps. In other words, match a simple pattern first, then for all of those results, see if they also match a more detailed pattern, etc.

Comment: @Dominic I think it’s not that complicated, the regex101 link with all the Unicode characters may look complex at first sight. And anything after the @ does not affect much the efficiency/steps, so the crucial part to be improved is just `(?<=[,\.:=\^ ]|\^[CJLcjl])((\^[BIUbiu])++)*@`

Comment: You have 6225 characters in your input string and two main choices at each step. Saying that, without counting backtracks (if any) it takes at least 12450 steps to reach the end of input string. But spaces take 7 steps for engine to skip and you have **894** occurrences of them there which adds ~6200 more steps to previous number. So it is ~18500 up to now. You have 10 successful matches that each one takes ~30 steps in average so 300 more to previous number. Now we are left at ~19K steps and engine shows ~20K. Do you want to reduce that 1K?

Comment: You may reduce extra steps for spaces however (if possible). That way you save that 6.2K steps said above.

Comment: @revo I would like to reduce that as much as I can. I saw that every software counts steps a little different, that’s not a problem. If you remove the `((\^[BIU34biu78])++)*` part before the `@`, instead of 20700 steps it does 537. So this part would be the one to improve.
When you say “reduce extra steps for spaces” you mean for all spaces and punctuation allowed in the assertion? How I could do that?

Comment: Check [this out](https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/5). It needs more work but can shine some light on it.

Comment: @revo thanks for your answer, I definitely didn't know all this "tricks". Now Regex101 is showing ~14k steps and 22ms, in contrast with 34ms. https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/7 
But a  test in my server shows this new regex being a 57% slower, I think that may not be an error, but some “steps” may take longer?

Comment: It all depends on your input string. Please [check this](https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/8) too.

Comment: @revo I removed things I think I don’t need, and I lowered your regex from 1.640 steps to 1.287 (v11).  
Then I applied all to the full regex and I got it at 1.403 steps (v13). Then I applied your “technique” adding `[^@^]++(*SKIP)(*F)|` to my original regex and it went from 19.616 steps 34ms to 1.094 steps 2ms (v14). So I thought well now this is going to be faster for sure, but, it is 1% slower on my server, just as fast as your version. This clearly tells me that somehow PHP 7.2 is no doing (*SKIP), and that was why times didn’t improved. I will research more on that.

Comment: PHP uses PCRE. It doesn't skip `(*SKIP)`. If you got what you wanted you don't need those micro optimizations.

Comment: [This is a revision of v14](https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/15)

Comment: @revo I finally figure it out, I was testing this on a Windows server, I tested it on Linux PHP 7.1.25, and the version with SKIP is x14 times faster, and not 1% slower. Regex101 showed x15 faster so it makes sense now. It is clear that on Windows platform SKIP is not working. I will have a look at v15.
I cannot thank you enough revo, you could put your v15 as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: That ("on Windows platform SKIP is not working"), or PHP 7.2 pre-optimizes the regex, but that's a feature of 7.3 with PCRE2.

Comment: We can't say SKIP verb doesn't work because if it isn't known to regex engine it should throw an error otherwise it is meant to operate. Maybe it is something else that caused the benchmarks to be way different. I'll post an answer regarding v15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A rule of thumb**:

> Do not let engine make an attempt on matching each single one character if
>   there are some boundaries.

The quote originally comes from this answer. Following regular expression reduces steps in a significant manner because of the left side of the outermost alternation, from ~20000 to ~900:

```
(?:[^@^]++|[@^]{2,}+)(*SKIP)(*F)
|
(?<=([HUGE-CHARACTER-CLASS])|\^[cjleqrd])
    (\^[34biu78])*+@([a-z\d][\w-.]{0,25}[a-z\d])(\^[34biu78])*+(?=(?1))
```

Actually I don't care much about the number of steps being reported by regex101 because that wouldn't be true within your own environment and it is not obvious if some steps are real or not or what steps are missed. But in this case since the logic of regex is clear and the difference is a lot it makes sense.

**What is the logic?**

We first try to match what probably is not desired at all, throw it away and look for parts that may match our pattern. `[^@^]++` matches up to a `@` or `^` symbols (desired characters) and `[@^]{2,}+` prevents engine to take extra steps before finding out it's going nowhere. So we make it to fail as soon as possible.

You can use `i` flag instead of defining uppercase forms of letters (this may have a little impact however).

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lTPUOf/17)

Comment: The u flag for unicode, PHP gives error if not included.

Comment: You're not matching multibyte characters and you don't need to. What error is it?

Comment: "Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large". The punctuation characters are from all languages, so there might be multibyte ones.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't bother to take a look at that monstrous character class. You need `u`.