# Speed up regular expression

Tags: java, regex, performance

This is a regex to extract the table name from a SQL statement:

```
(?:\sFROM\s|\sINTO\s|\sNEXTVAL[\s\W]*|^UPDATE\s|\sJOIN\s)[\s`'"]*([\w\.-_]+)
```

It matches a token, optionally enclosed in `` [`'"] ``, preceded by FROM etc. surrounded by whitespace, except for UPDATE which has no leading whitespace.

We execute many regexes, and this is the slowest one, and I'm not sure why. SQL strings can get up to 4k in size, and execution time is at worst 0,35ms on a 2.2GHz i7 MBP.

This is a slow input sample: https://pastebin.com/DnamKDPf

Can we do better? Splitting it up into multiple regexes would be an option, as well if alternation is an issues.

Comment: Can you provide an expected input/output ?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Some SQL string are truncated becaue they are too long, and then they have no `FROM table` at all. But most probably have it near the end of the string if they are particularly long, because of a huge list of auto-generated column definitions at the beginning.

Comment: I'd suggest shrinking the pattern to `(?:\s(?:(?:FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s|NEXTVAL)|^UPDATE\s)\W*([\w._-]+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/CC2oDa/1 (12,471 vs. 22976 steps)

Comment: Shouldn't affect speed but `[\s\W]` is same as `\W`, and I hope you know `[\w\.-_]` includes all letters, numbers, and `./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`.

Comment: Ok, no one mentions it but the regex optimization rule here is to *avoid the subsequent indefinitely-quantified patterns to match the same chars*. When it comes to alternation, *make sure the alternatives do not match the same text at the same location (i.e. avoid `(\sLl\s|\sWw\s)`, use `\s(Ll|Ww)\s`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [rule of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082150/1020526):

> Do not let engine make an attempt on matching each single one character if there are some boundaries.

Try the following regex (~2500 steps on the given input string):

```
(?!FROM|INTO|NEXTVAL|UPDATE|JOIN)\S*\s*|\w+\W*(\w[\w\.-]*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxQRPu/1)

**Note**: What you need is in the first capturing group.

The final regex according to comments (which is a little bit slower than the previous clean one):

```
(?!(?:FROM|INTO|NEXTVAL|UPDATE|JOIN)\b)\S*\s*|\b(?:NEXTVAL\W*|\w+\s[\s`'"]*)([\[\]\w\.-]+)
```

Comment: This one is very fast, but... doesn't work? There are more than 200 match groups, the first one just conains "select".

Comment: Please mind the last sentence *What you need is in the **first** capturing group*. You need to iterate over values of capturing group 1.

Comment: I see you changed the regex from `(?!FROM|INTO|NEXTVAL|UPDATE|JOIN)\S*\s*|\w+\W*(\w[\w\.-_]*)` to `(?:\s(?:(?:FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s|NEXTVAL)|^UPDATE\s)\W*([\w._-]+)`. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok, its about twice as fast on average - nice! Doesn't handle sub-selects well though. Example:
`select * from ( select distinct materialwa0_.id as col_0_0_ from PDMBOM2.materialways materialwa0_ where materialwa0_.name=? and materialwa0_.revision=? ) where rownum <= ?`
Expected: "PDMBOM2.materialways"
     but: was "select"

Comment: @MichaelBöckling I made a change to the right side of pipe. Try this instead https://regex101.com/r/MxQRPu/2

Comment: That one again doesn't work. I'm seeing this regex: `(?!FROM|INTO|NEXTVAL|UPDATE|JOIN)\S*\s*|\w+\s[\s`'"]*(\w[\w\.-_]*)`

Comment: @MichaelBöckling Do you see those strings in green? It confirms that it matches right chunks.

Comment: Maybe its a difference between Java and PCRE? Because `matcher.find()` does not return true.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling I made a Java live demo. Please see it here https://ideone.com/BnJKHD

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it out.

Comment: That looks quite good. Two regressions I can't figure out:

`SELECT updated FROM ticket_Ticket WHERE fk_customer = ? ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1`
Expected: "ticket_Ticket"
     but: was "FROM"
and `SELECT nextval('wsid_sequence') as next_value`
Expected: "wsid_sequence"
     but: was null

Comment: @MichaelBöckling Right I was expecting that. According to your regex this wouldn't need a patch anymore. Please check the update here https://regex101.com/r/MxQRPu/4

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now just two cases remaining, tried to fix but couldn't figure it out: https://pastebin.com/T93Pehfw

Comment: @MichaelBöckling You are adding to your requirements. If you continue to do so this will be endless.

Comment: @MichaelBöckling In  the first query you should expect `category_balance` and `category` not `category_balance` alone and the regex returns both https://regex101.com/r/MxQRPu/5

Comment: @MichaelBöckling I included brackets to character class. This is the final https://regex101.com/r/MxQRPu/6

Comment: I'm sorry if I asked too much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MichaelBöckling I'm glad to answer questions but knowing the requirements as clear as possible is basically an important thing. I updated the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: I ran the old regex and the new regex against a few thousand SQLs and compared their matches - the "spec" is basically the old regex, but I understand it is very hard to build a faster equivalent with the same behaviour. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @MichaelBöckling Did you really want this `[\w\.-_]`? I suspect it had to be `[\w\.\-_]` which is equal to `[\w\.-]`.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` optimisation is a very complex topic and should be done with help of some tools. For example, I like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) which calculates for us number of steps `Regex` engine had to do to match `pattern` to `payload`. For your `pattern` and given example it prints:

```
1 match, 22976 steps (~19ms)
```

First thing which you can always do it is grouping similar parts to one group. For example, `FROM`, `INTO` and `JOIN` look similar, so we can write regex as below:

```
(?:\s(?:FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s|\sNEXTVAL[\s\W]*|^UPDATE\s)[\s`'"]*([\w\.-_]+)
```

For above example, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), prints:

```
1 match, 15891 steps (~13ms)
```

Try to find some online tools which explain and optimise `Regex` such as [myregextester](https://www.myregextester.com/) and calculate how many steps engine needs to do.

Comment: I ran it against a large corpus of SQL statements, the regex is perfectly equivalent but unfortunately slightly slower on average (0,177 vs. 0,179).

Comment: Probably this part of regex does not count so much when it is tested against large set of SQL statements. Nevertheless my answer is not a final solution but rather a process how to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because matches are often near the end, one possibility would be to essentially start at the end and backtrack, rather than start at the beginning and forward-track, something along the lines of

```
^(?:UPDATE\s|.*(?:\s(?:(?:FROM|INTO|JOIN)\s|NEXTVAL[\s\W]*)))[\s`'\"]*([\w\.-_]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/SO7M87/1/ (154 steps)

While this may be *much* faster when a match exists, it's only a moderate improvement when there's no match, because the pattern must backtrack all the way to the beginning ([~9000](https://regex101.com/r/SO7M87/2) steps from [~23k](https://regex101.com/r/4PfTvK/1) steps)

Comment: Don't know SQL syntax myself, so I don't know the pitfalls or other possibilities such a pattern must account for, but there may well be a nice pattern involving `(?:\S+ AS \S+, )*` or something like it, to consume the huge columns at the beginning

Comment: Thats already faster, but its not quite equivalent because the match order has changed. An example comparing it to the old regex, where it matched the JOIN instead of the FROM: 
`SELECT * FROM order_refactor o LEFT JOIN order_data od ON o.id = od.order_id WHERE o.id = :id
Expected: "order_refactor"
     but: was "order_data"`

Comment: I benched "consume the huge columns", but it was slightly slower.

Comment: Are you certain about the performance on different input stings?